# How to open generated souce code from an apk file as a single project file in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I have decompiled the apk into its source code. But I'm being able to open the classes only seperately in Android Studio. I'm unable to find the Project file with Android Studio thumbnail. How is it done? I just want to understand which are built in classes and which are user defined.  Please help

Answer (score 0):

There is no "project file" inside the apk. All the information for the project is useless for the app to work on your phone, it would just increase the weight of the file. 
The apk contains all the classes and resources bundled to be installed and executed on your phone, nothing more.

Comment: I was asking about the Android Studio not apk. I have decomplied the apk.  It's just when I click on File->Open, I can open the project file(with Android Studio thumbnail) which include all the classes normally, but I can't open such a file in Android Studio from the extracted folder containing all classes and resources because I can't find it.I can only find the classes separately inside the extracted folder. Basically what I'm saying I'm unable to run the project inside Android Studio because I can't find the executable file. I'm only able to run the java classes separately.

Comment: heh, because the apk does not contain any file of that sort. It's just classes and resources. What is the point of including the whole metadata for project structure and settings when your phone does not need them?

Comment: it's like you buy a phone, you don't need all the datasheet of its components in order to use it, so they are not included with it. (it's kinda of an extreme example, but I could not come up with a better one)

Comment: So isn't there any way to run a decompiled apk file on Android Studio's emulator? Please don't mind me asking. I just want to know.

Comment: You can install the apk on the android emulator inside android studio via adb with `adb install <apk-file>` from terminal (either android studio's terminal or your terminal in your pc).

Comment: So, start your android virtual machine from android studio, then give that command from terminal (you can make sure adb is connected by giving `adb devices` and see if the device is connected, then install)

Comment: for a complete documentation about how to use `adb` you can look here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html